# Custom controls on DataGrid Header (not ColumnHeader)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I want to extend DataGrid to add some controls on the very top of the DataGrid control (not in the column headers). In other words, I want to render some controls (add/del button, filter TextBox) in the top half of CustomDataGrid (which inherits from DataGrid), and then render DataGrid in the bottom half.

In my pages I want to use this CustomDataGrid and set its columns and other options, which I usually set for default DataGrid.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Create a `UserControl` that includes a `DataGrid` plus your additional controls located above the `DataGrid`, perhaps using a Grid with two rows for layout.
2. Add your additional controls directly to the `DataGrid` template.

I would go for option (1), although you are not extending `Datagrid`, it is much simpler to do.

Comment: Option 1 is not suitable, because I want to extend DataGrid. The second option is very interesting, but how to do that? I suppose there are many xaml to dublicate default DataGrid functionality...

Comment: Why do you need to extend DataGrid? Your UserControl can expose the DataGrid it contains, giving you the same result. Anyhow, yes, DataGrid, like all Silverlight controls has a ControlTemplate which you can modify.

Comment: If I use first option and create UserControl, how to define columns in any page xaml for grid, which nested in UserControl (without resetting grid)?

Comment: Ok, I will use UserControl as wrapper for default DataGrid .You I right.